# fetching different arrays using preidicate filering "NSPredicates"

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, filtering, nspredicate

i have an array with NSstring values in it, now i wanna filter them out, and create sub arrays based on their 1st letter, example if i have array value america and brazil in an array i want two arrays to be created one having america based on its first letter 'a' and second one with brazil i.e first letter being'b'.
now i am using **(NSarray)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate** for this.

```
-(void)addArrayToMutableArray:(NSArray *) tableDataArrayObj
{

portArrayMutableObj = [[NSMutableArray array]alloc];
unichar value =65;
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
{
  predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%c", value+i ];
//not able to make predicate exp and not able to make it search my string the way i want.

  NSLog(@"decimal char %@", predicate);

filtered  = [tableDataArrayObj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

 //half implemeted, wanna add this filtered array to main array also.   
}
```

now i am struck at creating this predicate, and not ble to get my *tableDataArrayObj.substring indexat:0* for checking purpose, also i am not able to make a regular expression properly. filtered is another array, that i will use each time to add array returned from this func to be added in my main array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)(value + i)];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", letter];
```